# TextView to display formatted file in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I want to use a UITextView to display the contents of a formatted file.  I have various tutorials that I want to display.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: I think Text View will be better for that purpose

Answer (score 0):

To use rich text. It is NSAttributedString in Cocoa.

As Apple says:

> NSAttributedString : A string that has associated attributes (such as
>   visual style, hyperlinks, or accessibility data) for portions of its
>   text.

Why not use UITextView if the file has multiple lines?

Comment: I meant UITextView, Called it UI Text Field by mistake.

Comment: @SysX You can (and should) [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45897630/edit) your question at any time to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your users won't need to edit your various tutorials, another suggestion would be to load an HTML string (from a file or resource) into a **UIWebView**.  This might make it easier for you to generate your content to be presented.  It also gives you additional options for things like links, images, etc.